# apt update issues via docker container ansible playbook

Tags: apt, docker, ansible

I have been trying to run an ansible playbook via a docker container, However I'm having issues with sudo apt update currently running ubuntu 18.04:

[image: ansible playbook running]

I’ve also tried to SSH into each VM (which isn't an issue) and apt update as well.

[image: ansible playbook]

Comment: What about `docker attach`? You just need to update apt? `docker attach` will attach your running daemon to the 0,1, and 2 file descriptors of whatever terminal you run the command from. The man_page is under `man docker-attach`. Or you can run it as a devcontainer in vscode if you get really desperate... XD

Comment: I actually realized that the issue was my access from my virtual network to the internet thx!

Comment: Glad you solved it. You should add an answer. It may save somebody else some stress in the future

Answer (score 0):

due to some rules that i had implemented, access was not allowed to the virtual network on my newly added virtual machine, this is the reason the virtual machine was having issues updating, to fix this I made sure to write a corrective rule via my Microsoft Azure account that would allow this to take place.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).